# ASP.NET Core MVC generates an exception error when referencing a database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following code in a controller which, when executed, displays the view to the user in the browser:

```
public class PlayerController : Controller

{
    private readonly IPlayerRepository repo;
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Player person)
    {
        var lastName = person.LastName;
        var firstName = person.FirstName;
        var callPlayer = new PlayerInit();
        var returnPlayer = callPlayer.SetUpPlayer(lastName, firstName);

        return View();
    }
}
```

When I add this code, an exception is thrown:

```
    public PlayerController(IPlayerRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
```

This is the exception that gets thrown:

[image]

I have similar code in a different controller and I am able to run that controller to access a mySql database via dapper and display the results to the view.  Im not sure why the code in this particular controller is having an issue.

Thank you!

Comment: The error is clear and has nothing to do with databases. Have you registered any  `IPlayerRepository`-derived class? What does your Startup.cs look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this error is caused because in the Startup.cs file the ConfigureServices method does not contain the code that will inject the dependency to the container.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // OMITTED

    services.AddScoped<IPlayerRepository, PlayerRepository>();

    // OMITTED
}
```

You can also take a look to the documentation on how all the dependency injection works in dotnet starting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage).